# Pandas multilevel index messing with type?

Tags: python, pandas

Ok, I am on Pandas 0.21 and I try to get my head over the following odd feature:

```
x = pd.Series(index=[[pd.Timestamp("2015-05-14").date()]], data=[20.0])
y = pd.Series(index=[pd.Timestamp("2015-05-14").date()], data=[21.0])

print(type(pd.Timestamp("2015-05-14").date()))
print(type(x.index.get_level_values(0)[0]))
print(type(y.index[0]))
```

Here I construct two Series x and y. Both have only one element. x has a MultiIndex with only one level. y has a normal index. 
I would expect that all print statements result in

```
<class 'datetime.date'>
```

However, introducing the Multiindex messes up the type? 
I get

```
<class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem for performance reasons `date-likes` are converted to `DatetimeIndex`, see [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8802#issuecomment-62885623):

> Their was an inconsistency in how date-likes (datetime.date,datetime.datetime,Timestamp) were inferred in a MultiIndex level. This led to the creation of an object dtyped Index rather than a DatetimeIndex. datetime.date are second class objects in pandas as they are not efficiently represented.
>
> If you really really want to create this, you can do this:

```
In [8]: pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([Index([datetime.date(2013,1,1)]),['a']])
Out[8]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[[2013-01-01], [u'a']],
       labels=[[0], [0]])
```

---

So in your samples:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([pd.Index([pd.Timestamp("2015-05-14").date()]),['a']])
print (mux)
MultiIndex(levels=[[2015-05-14], ['a']],
           labels=[[0], [0]])
           
x = pd.Series(index=mux, data=[20.0])
y = pd.Series(index=[pd.Timestamp("2015-05-14").date()], data=[21.0])

print(type(pd.Timestamp("2015-05-14").date()))
<class 'datetime.date'>

print(type(x.index.get_level_values(0)[0]))
<class 'datetime.date'>

print(type(y.index[0]))
<class 'datetime.date'>
```